# Is There any application or extension that enables the mouse cursor follow the focused window in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, mouse, cursor

There are many question and answer I found on the internet that asks for focus following the mouse cursor. But I am looking for the opposite. Recently I have learned touch typing and I fell in love with the speed it provides. I use keypad mouse emulator to move the mouse cursor on rare occasions when there is no working keyboard shortcut. Half of my time while I am going to use the mouse; goes to move mouse cursor on to the focused window. It would be great if there is any gnome3 extension or any other option in ubuntu 18.04 that places the mouse cursor on the focused window? preferably in the center of the window.

Comment: Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/# and type "mouse focus" into the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/373545/644699), in Gnome, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> begins dragging the current window. If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> immediately afterwards, it will cancel dragging and leave the mouse in the center of the window.

Comment: Hey this is exactly what I wanted. I have edited the shortcut Alt+F7 to super+m so that I don't have to leave the home row. Really thanks.